# NextJS: How to update the state if the Link pointing at the same page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My code is here https://codesandbox.io/s/oo1lyw0mq9

Please try to go to lookup page. there are 3 links a, b, c. After clicking on each link, i want to see the `word` updated respectively to the link. I know my code is wrong but what's the right way to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
{this.props.word}
```

It's an anti-pattern to set state from props:

https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e

Your getInitialProps returns the props you need already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I know using this.props.word would work but with a complicated logic i would want to use state so that i can update the UI by changing the state

Comment: A <Link /> takes you to another page and hence the prop would be read in from the query. You could change them to just buttons and toggleState based on those clicks if you didn't navigate by Link.